# Type inference and implicit chaining

Tags: scala

*This is a simplified example*

I have the following code:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

trait Mapping[I, O]
trait KeyMapping[K, I, O]

implicit def toMapping[I, O](s: I => O): Mapping[I, O] = ???
implicit def toKeyMapping[K, I, O](s: (K, I => O))(
    implicit ev: (I => O) => Mapping[I, O]): KeyMapping[K, I, O] = ???

def test[K, I, O, M](s: M)(
    implicit ev: M => KeyMapping[K, I, O]
):KeyMapping[K, I, O] = ???

val x = test(1 -> {s:String => true})
            ^
```

This gives the following error:

```
type mismatch;
found: ((Int, Nothing => Boolean)) => KeyMapping[Int,Nothing,Boolean]
required: ((Int, String => Boolean)) => KeyMapping[Int,Input,Boolean]
```

Why is this?

Can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using an implicit converter instead of an implicit conversion.

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

trait Mapping[I, O]
trait KeyMapping[K, I, O]

trait MappingConverter[M, I, O] {
  def convert(m: M): Mapping[I, O]
}

trait KeyMappingConverter[M, K, I, O] {
  def convert(m: M): KeyMapping[K, I, O]
}

implicit def toMapping[I, O] =
  new MappingConverter[I => O, I, O] {
    def convert(m: I => O): Mapping[I, O] = ???
  }

implicit def toKeyMapping[K, I, O, M](
  implicit mapping: MappingConverter[M, I, O]) =
  new KeyMappingConverter[(K, M), K, I, O] {
    def convert(m: (K, M)): KeyMapping[K, I, O] = ???
  }

def test[K, I, O, M](s: M)(
  implicit converter: KeyMappingConverter[M, K, I, O]): KeyMapping[K, I, O] = ???

val x = test(1 -> { s: String => true })
```

Answer (score 1):

I was going to say:

```
  def test[K, I, O](s: (K, I => O))(
      implicit ev: ((K, I => O)) => KeyMapping[K, I, O]
  ):KeyMapping[K, I, O] = ???
```

No M, and notice the extra parens.  It will autotuple to try an apply, but not untuple.

You can use `-Ytyper-debug` in 2.11 (`-Yinfer-debug` in 2.10) to see it infer the `Nothing`.

Functions are contravariant in their inputs, so inferring `Nothing` means it's taking the widest type for your `I => O`. You could have competing `Mapping` conversions, one of which takes `Nothing`.

Comment: I actually need the `M`, I forgot to say it's a simplified example